# Why C is not taking value from structure?

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct

I have created structure and have given values for load, C and G. I want user to input load and it must match with one of the load from structure. 
Then the values of C and G for corresponding load should be taken for further calculation.
My problem is that whenever I enter load for example 1 then it must take value of C as 38 but instead it take 2293652. Even if I enter other value of load still it takes same.
I am from Mechanical background so don't go hard on me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct hook{
    float SL;
    int C;
    int G;
};

struct hook h[]={
    {0.5, 27, 14},
    {1, 38, 20},
    {2, 53, 27},
    {3.2, 68, 35},
    {5, 85, 42},
    {8, 107, 55},
    {10, 119, 60},
    {12, 134, 68},
    {16, 151, 76},
    {20, 169, 80},
    {25, 189, 90},
    {32, 207, 100}
};

int main()
{
    float SL1;
    int C1, G1;
    cout << "Enter the safe working load:\n" << endl;
    cin >> SL1;
    int i;
    i >=0;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof h /sizeof *h; i++){
        if(h[i].SL == SL1){
            h[i].C = C1;
            h[i].G = G1;
            break;
        }
    }

    float H=0.93*C1, M=0.6*C1, Z=0.12*C1;
    cout << C1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldnt these "h[i].C = C1;" be the other way around????

Comment: shouldnt sizeof*h be more sizeof(h[0]) ??

Comment: @Fattie `sizeof *h` and `sizeof h[0]` are equivalent in this context

Comment: I have question buddy if user enters value other than value provided in structure, so I want it to round up it to next higher value of load in structure, how that can be done?

Comment: @UnholySheep - oh right - in BOTH c and cpp, does an array decay to the first element?  thx

Comment: @Fattie C++ behaves the same as C for array to pointer decay, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying/1461449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt these "h[i].C = C1;" be the other way around??

It seems that was the issue!  :O